# Cloudbees RBAC plugin to list the groups for reporting

Tags: cloudbees

Can we use RBAC plugin in Jenkins CLI to list the groups and the members below it? I am able to find the users for each group using the syntax

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -i c:\.ssh\id_rsa group-membership path/to/folder GroupName
```

however, I would like to list all the groups for a particular folder and also list the members in the respective groups. I know later is achievable if we can list the available group names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no CLI command currently to list the groups in a given container. You could use `get-job path/to/folder` to retrieve its raw `config.xml`, which would include information about defined groups.

Comment: This works for me. Was able to extract the info from the config file to a excel. This is what I was looking for.